# Terminator (broken?) dependency

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, dpkg, apt

I'm trying to install terminator (term emulator) package on Debian 7.2 (stable) from `testing`:

```
Package: terminator
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

But `apt` complains:

```
# apt-get install terminator
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 terminator : Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What's strange is that the version of installed Python interpreters should fit the needs:

```
ii  python2.6                                                   2.6.8-1.1                          amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.6)

ii  python2.7                                                   2.7.3-6                            amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
```

How can I fix that? And why does terminator complain about supposedly unmet dependency?

(and please no jokes about missing `skynet` package as terminator's dependency ;-)

UPDATE:

I worked-around dependency problem by doing `apt-get download terminator` and then ignoring dependency when installing via `dpkg`, but I would still like to know the solution to this problem. Here's additional output:

```
% apt-cache policy terminator
terminator:
  Installed: 0.97-2
  Candidate: 0.97-2
  Package pin: 0.97-2
  Version table:
 *** 0.97-2 1000
        600 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.95-1 1000
        650 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages

% apt-cache depends terminator
terminator
  Depends: gconf2
    gconf2:i386
  Depends: python-dbus
  Depends: python-gobject
  Depends: python-gtk2
  Depends: python-vte
  Depends: <python:any>
    python:i386
    python
  Recommends: python-gnome2
  Recommends: python-keybinder
  Recommends: python-notify
  Recommends: xdg-utils
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy terminator` and `apt-cache depends terminator`?

Comment: @Braiam: see UPDATE pls

Answer (score 0):

Check and update your Software & Updates sources list. 
Ensure that under tab 'Other Software'
you have included `http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu`.